# Chef compile error when capturing shell output

Tags: shell, compiler-errors, output, chef-infra, lazy-evaluation

I have a chef recipe that looks something like this:

```
package 'build-essential' do
  action :install
end

cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("gcc -dumpversion")
cmd.run_command
gcc_version = cmd.stdout.strip()
```

If I execute the recipe on a system where gcc is installed, the recipe runs fine without errors. However, if I run the recipe on a system which doesn't have gcc install I get the error 'no such file or directory - gcc'.

I came to know about the chef two-phases stuff when trying to find a solution to my problem. I was expecting the package installation to satisfy the gcc requirement. How can I tell chef that this requirement will be satisfied later and not throw an error at compile time?

I tried the following, but the attribute does not get updated.

```
Chef::Resource::RubyBlock.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)
ruby_block "gcc_version" do
  block do
    s = shell_out("gcc -dumpversion")
    node.default['gcc_version'] = s.stdout.strip()
  end
end

echo "echo #{node[:gcc_version]}" do
  command "echo #{node[:gcc_version]}"
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So okay, a few issues here. First, forget that `Chef::Resource::whatever.send(:include` trick. Never do it, literally never. In this case, the ShellOut mixin is already available in all the places anyway.

Next, and more importantly, you've still got a two-pass confusion issue. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for details but basically the strings in that `echo` resource (I assume that said `execute` originally and you messed up the coping?) get interpolated at compile time. You haven't said what you are trying to do, but you probably need to use the `lazy{}` helper method.

And last, don't store things in node attributes like that, it's super brittle and hard to work with.

Comment: thanks. Basically, trying to get the installed gcc version. I am compiling and installing a library in my recipe. However, the library install paths include the compiler version. For ex., the install path could be '/usr/local/lib/libname/{gcc-ver}/abc. In my recipe, I need to access this path. Rest of the path is static except for the gcc version. I am trying to get the version into a local var. to construct the path. The build-essential pkg would have installed gcc. If my cmd was run after install, it'd have found gcc. However, my cmd is run at compile time i.e before gcc install.

Comment: Go the other way around, pick which version you want and put that in your recipe code :)

Comment: Not sure how I can do that. I don't know the version apriori. That's machine dependent. I am looking for a way to tell chef to not evaluate the shell expression during compile time.

Comment: You know it by forcing it: `package 'gcc' do version 'whatever' end` :)

Comment: I cannot force it because this recipe has to work for different os distributions and each of them will have different versions and I cannot restrict them to specific versions. Is there no other way to tell chef to ignore shell command evaluations at compile time?

Comment: There are lots of ways, but I wouldn't recommend them for a new user. Writing that kind of Chef code is very complex and easy to break.